# Converting HTML page into array of hexadecimal values for use in an Arduino server

Tags: c, bash, arduino, webserver

Lot of examples and tutorials of running web server on Arduino (or microcontrollers in general) use an gzipped Webpage in form of a hex-value array

```
#define index_ov2640_html_gz_len 4316
const uint8_t index_ov2640_html_gz[] = {
  0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08, 0x08, 0x50, 0x5C, 0xAE, 0x5C, 0x00, 0x03, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x65, 0x78, 0x5F,
  ...
  0x7F, 0x22, 0xF6, 0x5F, 0x04, 0x9C, 0x39, 0x76, 0x5C, 0x6C, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

I found some ways to manually convert the HTML into such an array, but I am searching for a way to perform the conversion automatically, for example with a bash script.

I found the `hexdump` tool and was able to produce some promising results with

```
hexdump -e '16/1 "0x%02X, " "\n"' ~/Dev/Arduino/CameraWebServer/www/index_ov2640.html.gz > test.txt
```

but there are some issues:

1. The resulting file contains (sometimes) one or more asterisks

```
0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
*
0x3C, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x70, 0x75, 0x74, 0x20, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3D, 0x22, 0x61, 0x65, 0x63, 0x32, 0x22,
```

2. The last line looks like this

```
0x6D, 0x6C, 0x3E, 0x0A, 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  , 0x  ,
```

Comment: Look for the bin2c.exe on the segger website

Comment: Lovely, thank you. I do not use Windows, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using this tool, https://github.com/gwilymk/bin2c I will also give this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/  a try

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my conversation with [Owen](http://easytarget.org/) I learned about the pointing me to the unix `xxd` tool providing exactly what I was searching for. The script I introduced previously can be thus simplified to:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_FILE=camera_index_new.h

# clear the output file
> $OUTPUT_FILE

for file in `ls *.html`; do
    echo "Compressing: $file"
    gzip -kf "$file" && \
    echo "Converting $file to byte array"
    echo "/* Contents of file "$file".gz */" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
    xxd -i -u $file".gz" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
    echo "" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

PREVIOUS SOLUTION:

Based on [P__J__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/p-j)s suggestion I made bash script based on the [bin2c](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/) project which produces output almost identical to what is used in the [espressif CameraWebServer exmple](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer)

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_FILE=camera_index.h

convert_to_byte_array() {
    echo "Converting $@ to byte arrays"
    ./bin2c -m -o $OUTPUT_FILE $@
}

for file in `ls *.html`; do
    echo "Compressing: $file"
    cp "$file" "copy_$file" && \
    gzip -f "$file" && \
    mv "copy_$file" "$file"
    compressed_files=( "${compressed_files[@]}" $file".gz")
done
if test -f "./bin2c"; then
    convert_to_byte_array ${compressed_files[@]}
elif test -f "./bin2c.c"; then
    echo "Compiling bin2c from the source"
    gcc -o bin2c bin2c.c
    convert_to_byte_array ${compressed_files[@]}
else
    echo "Conversion of ${compressed_files[@]} to byte arrays not possilbe, missing bin2c.
Download bin2c source (bin2c.c) fom https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/ and put it in this folder."
fi
```